# Nested Firebase querying based on an array of values ASYNC issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a complicated scenario where I query my firebase database for activity (likes, posts) by the user.
Then, using that data, I query again in order to find users with matching data. To do this, I used a solution of a forloop within the first query, in which on each iteration I make another reference to the database with a different keyword to query with.

Then, I must the list of users to find THEIR data and handle it in another way.

I come across issues with the async nature of the firebase queries, however. Because I cannot ensure when I will actually have the array of users, I cannot create another reference to firebase using the array of users, as it is still undefined. Additionally, I cannot make a callback function because I must call the callback in the firebase query, but it is in a forloop so it will greatly effect run time.

Are there any solutions to this? I was thinking it might be possible to simply move the handling of the users to componentDidUpdate after setting a "loading" state in componentDidMount to false, but that seems like an improper usage of componentDidUpdate as I feel as though I should have all my data after componentDidMount.

Here is a code snippet:

```
componentDidMount(){
firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurant_Tags").orderByChild("Author_ID")
                      .equalTo("test").once('value', (snap) =>{

      var queryObject = snap.val();
      var tagKeys = Object.keys(queryObject);
      var uniqueRestaurants = {};
      for(var i = 0; i < tagKeys.length; i++){
        if(!(queryObject[tagKeys[i]]["Restaurant_ID"] in uniqueRestaurants)){
          uniqueRestaurants[queryObject[tagKeys[i]]["Restaurant_ID"]] = 1;
        }
      }

      for(var key in uniqueRestaurants){
        this.uniqueRestaurantsArray.push(key);
      }

      //finding users with same restaurant tags
      for(var i = 0; i < this.uniqueRestaurantsArray.length; i++){
        firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurant_Tags").orderByChild("Restaurant_ID")
                              .equalTo(this.uniqueRestaurantsArray[i])
                              .once('value', (snap) =>{
                var queryObject2 = snap.val();
                var keys = Object.keys(queryObject2);
                var foundUsers = {};
                for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
                  if(queryObject2[keys[j]]["Author_ID"] == "test"){
                    continue;
                  }
                  else{
                    if(!(queryObject2[keys[j]]["Author_ID"] in foundUsers)){
                      foundUsers[queryObject2[keys[j]]["Author_ID"]] = 1;
                    }
                  }
                }
                for(var key in foundUsers){
                  this.mutualUsers.push(key);
                }
                console.log(this.mutualUsers);
        });
      }
});
}
```

Comment: You probably want to chain promises with the promise returned by once() rather than using its callback, as you're doing now.  Chaining promises will make executing sequences of async work much easier, as the results from one async callback will be received as the input to the next callback in the chain.

Comment: What exactly would that look like? I'm not too familiar with using promises and I'm not sure how exactly to chain a promise with once rather than using another callback

Comment: Promises are something to serach for tutorials about. They're pretty foundational to JavaScript programming.

Comment: Regardless, I'm still a bit stuck to see why chaining promises would work differently than callbacks, as both methods are attempting to use previous results as input?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You can collect all the promises from all your queries into an array, then use Promise.all() to create a new promise that resolves when they are all complete.  At that point, you have all the data available in once place.

Comment: New update: I do not think I can fix the issue with promises. I've been trying to get it to work but the issue still stands that I cannot successfully rely on the data being retrieved during the for loop as I cannot set a promise within that forloop because of optimization issues. More specifically, I return data on the condition that it is the last iteration of references, but I cannot make a promise with that last iteration of a reference specifically in anyway.

Comment: But for Promise.all(), it must be called in the same scope as where the data is being retrieved from correct? Which in my case is within the forloop. Then that data is only guaranteed to have been retrieved while in the scope of that promise. But then I need that data outside of the forloop. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: No, you call promise.all whenever you have an array of promises for all the async tasks you want to perform.   https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/

Comment: Even so, wouldn't the array of promises have to be from within the forloop? How would it be possible to reference them in the promise.all call once outside of that scope?

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific. If the promises are required outside of the first firebaseApp.database() entirely, how would one be able to call promise.all() on the data being retrieved in the for loop? Currently, my promise.all() returns before any of the data is actually being retrieved.